# Strange behavior of glVertexAttrib3f on one machine

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I have a very weird problem with my simple OpenGL application not working on my girlfriend's machine. At first I thought of all kinds of problems with my code, but I could finally break it down to this code not working (not working means: the triangle is drawn correctly, but black, that is, without the correct color):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/transform.hpp>

#include "../common/shader.h"


const GLfloat reticle_vertices[] =
{
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
};


glm::mat4 MVP;
glm::mat4 vp;


const char *vertexSource =
        "#version 150\n"
        "layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;"
        "layout(location = 1) in vec3 color;"
        "out vec3 fragColor;"
        "uniform mat4 MVP;"
        "void main() {"
        "gl_Position = MVP * vec4(position, 1.0);"
        "fragColor = color;"
        "}";

const char *fragmentSource =
        "#version 150\n"
        "in vec3 fragColor;"
        "out vec4 outColor;"
        "void main() {"
        "outColor = vec4(fragColor, 1.0);"
        "}";


// Key callback: exit on ESCAPE
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
        if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}


// Initialize and return a window with GLFW
GLFWwindow *initGLWindow(int width, int height, int samples, const char *title, GLFWkeyfun keycb)
{
        if (!glfwInit())
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
                return NULL;
        }
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, samples);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

        GLFWwindow *w = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, NULL, NULL);
        if (!w)
        {
                glfwTerminate();
                return NULL;
        }

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(w);
        glfwSetKeyCallback(w, keycb);

        glewExperimental = true;
        if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
                return NULL;
        }

        return w;
}


int main()
{
        // Initialize the OpenGL window
        GLFWwindow *window = initGLWindow(1024, 768, 2, "Schnuff", key_callback);

        // Load and use the shaders
        GLuint programID = LoadShaders(vertexSource, fragmentSource);
        glUseProgram(programID);

        // Get the attribute locations
        GLuint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "position");
        printf("posAttrib = %d\n", posAttrib);
        GLuint colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "color");
        printf("colAttrib = %d\n", colAttrib);
        //GLint normAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "normal");
        //printf("normAttrib = %d\n", normAttrib);
        GLuint mvpID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");

        // Vertex array object
        GLuint vao;
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);

        // Vertex buffer object
        GLuint vbo;
        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(reticle_vertices), reticle_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
        glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

        // Hide the cursor
        glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_HIDDEN);

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
        glm::mat4 m = glm::mat4(1.0f);

        // Main loop
        do
        {
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

                glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpID, 1, GL_FALSE, &m[0][0]);
                glVertexAttrib3f(colAttrib, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

                glfwSwapBuffers(window);
                glfwPollEvents();
        }
        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window));

        glDeleteProgram(programID);
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        glfwTerminate();
        return 0;
}
```

As far as I could figure it out, the problem **only** occurs because of the following: on her machine, `posAttrib = 1, colAttrib = 0`, while on mine it is the other way round. I tried using

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 color;
```

and then it works fine! Although once I exchange these numbers (I have yet to test it with other values and `#version 330 core\n`, but her laptop is offline at the moment), it stops working again...

I even found the following unanswered question [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608643/strange-glvertexattrib-behavior), which seems very closely related.

Did anyone of you encounter a similar behavior, or knows how to fix the whole situation without having to use `layout(location = x)`? Since I think in a larger project, setting every location by hand could be tedious or unwanted (correct me if I'm wrong there and this is actually the preferred way to do it!).

Yet to test: other values than 0 or 1, and the `#version` stuff, since on my machine I can't even use `layout(location = x)` without `#version 330 core` (which is again strange, because it apparently does *something* on her machine which makes it work).

I'm a newbie at OpenGL and thus totally confused here! :-)

Comment: Any suggestion on why it was downvoted? I can try to improve my post if you leave a hint :/

Comment: Inline that code.  Pastebins have a habit of disappearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a [driver bug](http://devgurus.amd.com/message/1285579) on my AMD card.

Using a VBO for the color array works:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/transform.hpp>

// GLSL shader program loader
struct Program
{
    static GLuint Load( const char* vert, const char* geom, const char* frag )
    {
        GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
        if( vert ) AttachShader( prog, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vert );
        if( geom ) AttachShader( prog, GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER, geom );
        if( frag ) AttachShader( prog, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, frag );
        glLinkProgram( prog );
        CheckStatus( prog );
        return prog;
    }

private:
    static void CheckStatus( GLuint obj )
    {
        GLint status = GL_FALSE, len = 10;
        if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
        if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
        if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &len );
        std::vector< char > log( len, 'X' );
        if( glIsShader(obj) )   glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, len, NULL, &log[0] );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) )  glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, len, NULL, &log[0] );
        std::cerr << &log[0] << std::endl;
        exit( -1 );
    }

    static void AttachShader( GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src )
    {
        GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
        glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
        glCompileShader( shader );
        CheckStatus( shader );
        glAttachShader( program, shader );
        glDeleteShader( shader );
    }
};
#define GLSL(version, shader) "#version " #version "\n" #shader

const char* vert = GLSL
    (
    150 core,
    in vec3 position;
    in vec3 color;
    out vec3 fragColor;
    uniform mat4 MVP;
    void main() 
    {
        fragColor = color;
        gl_Position = MVP * vec4(position, 1.0);
    }
);

const char* frag = GLSL
    (
    150 core,
    in vec3 fragColor;
    out vec4 outColor;
    void main()
    {
        outColor = vec4(1.0);
    }
);


const GLfloat reticle_vertices[] =
{
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
};

const GLfloat colors[] =
{
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
};


// Key callback: exit on ESCAPE
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}


// Initialize and return a window with GLFW
GLFWwindow *initGLWindow(int width, int height, int samples, const char *title, GLFWkeyfun keycb)
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, samples);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow *w = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, NULL, NULL);
    if (!w)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return NULL;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(w);

    glfwSetKeyCallback(w, keycb);

    glewExperimental = true;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    while( glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR ) {}

    return w;
}


int main()
{
    // Initialize the OpenGL window
    GLFWwindow *window = initGLWindow(1024, 768, 2, "Schnuff", key_callback);

    // Hide the cursor
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_HIDDEN);

    // Load and use the shaders
    GLuint programID = Program::Load( vert, NULL, frag );
    glUseProgram(programID);

    // Vertex array object
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    // Vertex buffer object
    GLuint posVbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &posVbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posVbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(reticle_vertices), reticle_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint colorVbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &colorVbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorVbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(colors), colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    // Main loop
    while( !glfwWindowShouldClose(window) )
    {
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glm::mat4 m = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        GLuint mvpID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpID, 1, GL_FALSE, &m[0][0]);

        GLuint posPos = glGetAttribLocation( programID, "position" );
        glEnableVertexAttribArray( posPos );
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posVbo);
        glVertexAttribPointer( posPos, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0 );

        GLuint colorPos = glGetAttribLocation( programID, "color" );
        // broken
        //glDisableVertexAttribArray( colorPos );
        //glVertexAttrib3f( colorPos, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
        // works
        glEnableVertexAttribArray( colorPos );
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorVbo);
        glVertexAttribPointer( colorPos, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0 );

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteProgram(programID);
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the driver bug link! I wouldn't have found that :) The thing about using the colors in a buffer object is: I have some more objects, like voxels, which are all uniformly colored and can share the same constant vertex array. That's why I don't want to put the color into an array, since it's changing from object to object. But I think I'm just going to fix the location of `position` to 0. Also I'm going to try a uniform instead of `in vec3 color;`, since the color is invariant per draw call.